# Unable to impersonate - Jackrabbit

Tags: java, jackrabbit, jcr

I have custom type node `et:document` which needs to shared among some users in jackrabbit repository.

But when I try to impersonate as superuser and assign to each user, a defined property `sharedWithMe`, getting `failed login exception`.

Log in as application user,

```
SimpleCredentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials(userName, password.toCharArray());
Session session = repository.login(credentials, "default");
```

Trying to share documents(with property added to user node)

```
SimpleCredentials credentials = new SimpleCredentials("superuser", "superuser".toCharArray());
Session adminUser = session.impersonate(credentials);
UserManager userManager = ((JackrabbitSession) adminUser).getUserManager();

for(String userID : users) {
    User user = (User) userManager.getAuthorizable(userID);
    Value value = vf.createValue(docPath);
    Value[] sharedDocsPath =  user.getProperty("sharedWithMe");
    int shareDocIndex = 0;
    Value[] revisedSharedDocPath = null;

    if (null != sharedDocsPath && sharedDocsPath.length > 0) {
        revisedSharedDocPath = new Value[sharedDocsPath.length + 1];

        for (Value v : sharedDocsPath) {
            revisedSharedDocPath[shareDocIndex] = v;
            shareDocIndex++;
        }
        revisedSharedDocPath[shareDocIndex] = value;
    } else {
        revisedSharedDocPath = new Value[1];
        revisedSharedDocPath[shareDocIndex] = value;
    }

    user.setProperty("sharedWithMe", revisedSharedDocPath);
}
```

getting exception:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: attempt to impersonate denied for superuser
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule.impersonate(DefaultLoginModule.java:306)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.AbstractLoginModule.login(AbstractLoginModule.java:330)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.LocalAuthContext.login(LocalAuthContext.java:86)
```

Security tag info in repository.xml

```xml
<Security appName="EnterpriseManager">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager">
        <WorkspaceAccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleWorkspaceAccessManager"/>
    </SecurityManager>
    <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager"/>
    <LoginModule class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authentication.DefaultLoginModule">         
        <param name="adminId" value="superuser"/>
    </LoginModule>
</Security>

<Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
    <WorkspaceSecurity>               
        <AccessControlProvider class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.authorization.principalbased.ACLProvider">
            <param name="omit-default-permission" value="true" />
        </AccessControlProvider>
    </WorkspaceSecurity>
</Workspace>
```

Using JCR 2.0, Jackrabbit 2.6

Answer (score 1):

First need to grant impersonation to principal and then impersonate.(bit wierd though)

```
boolean isGranted = impersonation.grantImpersonation(repoUser.getPrincipal());
System.out.println("Granted impersonation for user? " + isGranted);

SimpleCredentials adminCredentials = new SimpleCredentials(suUser, suPassword.toCharArray());
session = (JackrabbitSession) session.impersonate(adminCredentials);
```